# Android - Passing serializable or parcelable in bundle between services on different apk

Tags: android, serialization, process, parcelable, serializable

I'm developing a message interface between services that belongs to different Android apks.

The sender service can send a message, implemented as a `Bundle`, to the receiver service.
Primitive types like String or boolean are correctly exchanged.

The following step is to exchange more complex objects, that are defined in a library, shared between the different services.
These objects implement the `Parcelable` or the `Serializable` interface, so that they can be encapsulated inside a `Bundle`, using the `putParcelable` and `putSerializable` methods.

Unfortunately, this solution does not work. In the bundle object received by the service, the parcelable (or serializable) object is substituted by a `String`. It seems that Android calls the `toString` method of the object before sending the Bundle to the receiver service.

Is there any solution of this problem without implementing methods that can serialize each object to a `Bundle` formed by only primitive types?

Comment: What happens when you call `getParcelable()` from the Bundle? Do you get null?

Comment: there is something wrong in your code: you can easily pass any `Parcelable` in Binder transactions

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe when I call `getParcelable()` performing a cast to the expected type, a class cast exception is thrown because the element in the `Bundle` is considered as a `String` object.

Comment: so for example [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable) doesn't work at you?

Comment: I feel like there is something wrong with how you implemented your `Parcelable` interface. Could you maybe post some code of one of your Parcelables to show an example of one of them that fails?

Comment: I followed an example very similar to the one posted by @pskink. I don't think that it is a problem with my `Parcelable` implementation because the same error happens also if the class implements the `Serializable` interface.

Comment: so the example i posted doesn't work?

Comment: @pskink no it doesn't. But if we assume that my `Parcelable` implementation is wrong, the `Serializable` version should work, since I don't need to implement anything and thus I can't make any mistake. I think that the problem comes out when the Bundle is passed from the first application process to the second one, that is deployed as a different application and apk.

Comment: so if you do: `parcelable = intent.getParcelableExtra("parcelable");` what is `parcelable.getClass().toString();` ?

Comment: @pskink: `Key p expected Parcelable but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned. Attempt to cast generated internal exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:792)`

Comment: and, do you know what you did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can always exchange `Base64`ed objects as strings, and Strings can be made from `ByteArray`s so there's an idea you can try.

You can actually pass alot of things via Strings when you think about it :)

Comment: You are right. For now, I serialize the object to JSON so that it can be passed as a `String`, but I'm looking for a better solution, if it is possible.